# Как изменить параметры блока при меньшем разрешении экрана? JS

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как верно изменить этот скрипт, чтобы при разрешении экрана меньше 420px высота блока detail_text изменяла значение? Сейчас при любом разрешении экрана выставляется значение в 200px, что не подходит для мобильных телефонов. Копала в сторонуmatchMedia, но что-то идет не так.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var element_detail_text = $("#detail_text").html();

    $("#detail_text_resize").show();

    function resize_text_field(){
        if(document.getElementById("detail_text").offsetHeight > 200){
            document.getElementById("detail_text").style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("detail_text").style.height = "200px";
            document.getElementById("detail_text_resize").style.display = "";
        }
    resize_text_field();
    onload = function(){ resize_text_field() }

    function element_detail_show(){
        $("#detail_text_resize").hide();
        document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='';
        document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='auto';
        $("#detail_text_minimize").show();
    }

    function element_detail_hide(){
        $("#detail_text_minimize").hide();
        document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='200px';
        document.getElementById('detail_text_resize').style.display='inline-block';
        document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='hidden';
        $("#detail_text_resize").show();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: вам именно по js нужно ибо же и css подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может такой пример Вам поможет.

```js
function changeHeight(){
 var element = document.getElementById("detail_text");

 if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 420px)").matches) {
  element.style.height = "100px";
 } else {
  element.style.height = "200px";
 }
}
changeHeight();

window.addEventListener("resize", changeHeight);
```

```css
#detail_text{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="detail_text" >detail_text</div>
```

Но, проще сделать через CSS media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
    #detail_text{
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: здравствуйте. Я пробовала через CSS media queries, но приходится дополнительно прописывать !important и все-равно работает криво. Т.е.  при попытки раскрыть текст полностью, он накладывается на нижний текстовый блок. Поэтому хочу попробовать прописать в самом скрипте разное поведение для разных размеров окна. Предполагаю, что это может решить проблему. Спасибо, сейчас попробую воспользоваться предложенным вами примером

Comment: Вообще, как раз для этого и существуют CSS media queries, что бы адаптировать вашу страницу для всех экранов. Кстати, Вы код с media queries поместили в самый низ стилей?

Comment: да, конечно. Может так происходит из-за того, что стили для этого элемента, которые определяются в скрипте, прописываются инлайн?

Comment: Да, конечно инлайновые стили в приоритете. Так что лучше Вам их убрать в основной файл. Есть такая возможность?

Comment: да,думаю есть, у меня просто очень плохо с JS, от того сложно разобрать этот скрипт, чтобы он стал более гибкий в управлении

Comment: @Alla Скрипт Вам не нужен будет вообще. Вы все это можете сделать на CSS на много легче и удобнее. На JS стоит это делать, если в CSS не получается. Не стоит усложнять...

Comment: да это же гениально, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Alla Не за что! Если мой ответ помог Вам, просто отметьте его как правильный )) Спасибо